# Film where an android deceives and takes over a space ship. Quotes Ozymandias and plays Wagner

Tags: story-identification, movie

Here's what I remember:

- A spaceship with crew and an android reaches a distant planet full of vegetation.
- Crew meets another criminal android remnant of previous mission
- Second android deceives all the crew and takes charge of the return journey, putting the crew in eternal hibernation and directs the spaceship to a distant constellation and orders Wagner music to be played.
- Criminal android quotes "Ozymandias" Shelley's poem

Also, they say the line "better a king in hell than servant in paradise"

Answer (score 8):

This is *[Alien: Covenant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alien:_Covenant)*

> Business magnate Peter Weyland speaks with his newly activated android, who chooses the name "David" after observing Michelangelo's eponymous statue. Weyland states that one day they will search for mankind's creator together. David comments on his own unlimited lifespan as compared to Weyland's, which unsettles Weyland.
>
> In 2104 CE, 11 years after the Prometheus expedition, the colonization ship Covenant is 7 years from reaching planet Origae-6 with 2,000 colonists in stasis and 1,140 human embryos in cold storage. The ship is monitored by Walter, an advanced android model that physically resembles David. When a solar flare[6] damages the ship, Walter reanimates his 14[7] human crewmates, themselves couples and future colonists. The ship's captain, Jake Branson, is burned alive when his stasis pod malfunctions. While repairing the ship, the crew picks up a transmission of a human voice from a nearby planet, which appears eminently more habitable than Origae-6. Despite the protests of Daniels, Branson's widow, that this new "perfect" planet is too good to be true, the new captain, Christopher Oram, decides they will investigate the new planet.

....

> Covenant resumes its voyage to Origae-6. As Walter puts Daniels in stasis, she realizes he is really David, but is unable to escape from her pod before falling asleep. David regurgitates two facehugger embryos, which he places in cold storage with the human embryos, and inspects the colonists. Posing as Walter, he sends a transmission in which he says all crewmembers except Daniels and Tennessee were killed by the earlier solar-flare incident.

### Ozymandias scene

### Trailer